# OH-TFS-Connector-0051 Test Result error when migrating from TFS 2013 to VS Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

We are trying to migrate an On-Prem TFS 2013 project to VS Team Services and getting the following error on 77 Work Items (all the same error):

> OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed createOrUpdateTestResult.
>   Server Error : Error occured while Create/Update Test Rrun caused
>   by:Date must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59
>   PM. Confirm that the date is correct.

This happened when we were trying to migrate 7 Team Projects (and we're just starting the process), such message don't provide us any clue about which one of the invoved Team Projects is the faulty one, also it doesn't seem possible that we could manually edit the source Work Items (Test Run) in order to fix the error.

We can provide the logs if needed.

Comment: Can you share the logs? It locates at the "logs" folder under opshub installation path.

Comment: Sure, here they are http://1drv.ms/1RIpQBP

Comment: Can you check the "Date Completed" value for the linked test run of Work Item 17612? Include the latest revision and history revision.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in the latest release of OVSMU. However, from the new version onward, some migration features are no longer a part of the Free Version of the tool. Please refer the Gallery [Page](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2) for a complete list of functionalists between version in the latest release.